# Simple CSS spinner element wobbles while rotating

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to create a simple css spinner which is shown while my page is loading by using a pseudo element overlaying a div where content will be shown.
It uses `border-radius` and `transform: rotate()` to achieve this effect but as you can see it wobbles strangely while rotating. The effect is more or less obvious depending on the screen size, zoom level and browser. I find it's most visible in MS Edge.

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfsqebsn/4/)

```css
.loading {
  width: 75vh;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}

.loading::after {
    border: 6vmin solid lightblue;
    border-top: 6vmin solid darkblue;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 5vmin;
    margin-left: 5vmin;
    width: 15vmin;
    height: 15vmin;
    content: "";
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: spin .5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading"></div>
```

Comment: `can see it wobbles strangely`:can you elaborate ? don't forget you are using bezier

Comment: I mean the wobble translates the entire spinner slightly. I'm not talking about the rotation effect - it would be the same if set to linear with a lower duration.

Comment: add `position: relative;` to loading

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks for pointing it out. It's already on my actual page I just forgot to add it to the fiddle. I updated it accordingly. I also changed the spinner animation to linear and .5s so the wobble is more visible.

Comment: not able to see any strange wobbles, tried Chrome, FF and IE

Comment: I see it more clearly in the fiddle with 392 * 400 pixel container size than in the code snippet window here. But I can see it in Firefox, Chrome and Edge in most situations except for some screen dimensions or when zooming in to a specific level. I even tried it on firefox on another machine and it also wobbles clearly.

Comment: maybe a simple optical illusion .. i still see nothing :)

Comment: The wobble is a lie. Nothing is wobbling, it's just an optical illusion. I changed the border color and the wobble is gone. I don't think you can do anything to "fix" it.

Comment: I see the wobble on IE. Looks somewhat like a 1px up and down jump. Seems to get worse as the viewport gets smaller. Interesting issue

Comment: hmm I changed the border color to red and yellow and it was still wobbeling - but it was gone after I resized it. So I don't think it's actually an optical illusion but it's very strange.

Comment: some sub-pixel issue of sorts?

Comment: Possibly - I also noticed the circle is sometimes rendered with some "dents" at the edges instead of perfectly circularly. Not sure if that is related. Maybe I should stick to squares in the future..

Comment: Seems to be some weird issue with border-radius. Getting rid of it *"fixes"* the wobble, but of course lets the boxes boxy.  Been trying quite some things without success... at this point I'd say better use other technique to draw the thing.

Answer (score 1):

There's some weird cut going on with the border-radius
Change it to border-radius: 1000px and see what happens

Comment: I just checked, same result. You're right that it's something weird with border-radius though, as getting rid of it (therefore making squares) "fixes" the problem..

Comment: It does look like this is the case. I guess that means I'll have to find another method for drawing (SVG with dashoffset?) or just try a different design altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the width and height to a pixel value seems to fix the issue. It may not be the best solution, but hey, it works.

To make this appropriate for all screen sizes, you need to use @media. In the bottom of the css I have added one that changes the size if the screen size is smaller than 700px just to show you how to do it, and if you want to change the numbers around or something, you at least know how @media can be used :)

Here is the code for changing the size depending on the screen-size of the users device.

```
@media (max-width: 700px){
  .loading::after {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

If you want to make it different on large screens too, just swap out "max-width: 700px" with "min-width: 1500px" or a value of your choice :)

http://jsfiddle.net/hfsqebsn/5/

Again, there are probably better ways, but this works :)

Edit: I think I may have changed around some other stuff in the fiddle I linked for testing purposes, so just beware of that :P

Comment: Using pixel values directly does make it less visible. You can still see slight single pixel offsets in Edge though. I think the reason this works is simply because it fixes the size to one that exerts less wobble.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was driving me crazy all day. I was able to solve it personally by making the ring thicker than desired and then masking over its inner and outer portions to hide the wobble from the viewer.

Solution.
https://codepen.io/corbinmosher/pen/GRWmYjy

Solution with background coloring to help with understanding it.
https://codepen.io/corbinmosher/pen/bGqWmEj

```
<div class="spinner__container">
  <div class="spinner__ring"></div>
  <div class="spinner__outline"></div>
</div>

.spinner__container {
  position: relative;
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  
  background-color: white;
}

.spinner__ring {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  width: calc(100% - 8px);
  height: calc(100% - 8px);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.spinner__ring:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;

  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  height: calc(100% + 2px);

  border: 10px solid lightblue;
  border-top: 10px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: rotate-spinner 1s linear infinite;
}

.spinner__ring:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  width: calc(100% - 8px);
  height: calc(100% - 8px);

  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;

  background-color: white;
}

.spinner__outline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  width: calc(100% - 8px);
  height: calc(100% - 8px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 2px white;
}

@keyframes rotate-spinner {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(405deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(765deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate-spinner {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(405deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(765deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: @NNseum please check this answer.